# Could not instantiate feature[compiler.ExpressionFactory]: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl

Tags: java, itext, java-ee-6

I am trying to use `lowagie (iText) 2.1.7` on `Websphere 8.5`

I am getting the following error:

```
Could not instantiate feature[compiler.ExpressionFactory]: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.
```

Without this jar everything works fine.

I've tried adding it as a maven dependency and also as an external jar, but it still doesn't work.

I took some steps in trying to fix the problem like adding the `el-impl-1.0.jar` or the `el-ri.1.0.jar` but I didn't have any luck.

I am using `servlet version 2.5` and `java 1.6`

Comment: Why are you using iText 2.1.7 (dating from July 2009) instead of iText 5.5.5 (dating from 2015). Seems that you're making the wrong choices from the start.

Comment: We are using older technologies as requested by our client, I thought a newer version of iText may need dependencies that we can't add.

Comment: Newer versions of iText require Java 1.5 and you are using Java 1.6, so you are fine with respect to dependencies. It is your duty to inform your customer that iText 2.1.7 should no longer be used for the following reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Bruno for the answers, the problem was related to the fact that I was running out of space on the drive and I assume Maven didn't have enough space to download the dependencies.